# How can I check if a generic type implements an interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Just to give you some context I'm writing some test classes to test the CRUD operations of my repository using .NET 6.0.

I'm working with two interfaces:

1- `IEntity` is an empty base interface for all my objects.

```
public interface IEntity { }
```

2- `IIdentifiableEntity<T>` that implements `IEntity` and lets me know that the object has an `Id` property.

```
public interface IIdentifiableEntity<T> : IEntity
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have created two test classes, one for each type of interface:

1- `TestIEntity` to test objects implementing the `IEntity` interface.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestIEntity<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test() {
        // Test objects of type IEntity
        // Assert.IsNotNull(repository.GetAll());
    }
}
```

2- `TestIIdentifiableEntity` to test objects implementing the `IIdentifiableEntity`. (in my case I'm only interested in testing objects that have an `Id` of type `long`)

```
[TestClass]
public class TestIIdentifiableEntity<T>
    where T : IIdentifiableEntity<long>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test() {
        // Test instances of type IIdentifiableEntity<long>
        // Assert.IsTrue(repository.GetId(1).Id > 0);
    }
}
```

I have created two base abstract test classes that create the corresponding test class and invoke the test methods. It looks something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class TestBase<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIEntity()
    {
        TestIEntity() testClass = new TestIEntity();
        testClass.Test();        
    }
}

[TestClass]
public abstract class TestBaseId<T>
    where T : IIdentifiableEntity<long>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIIdentifiableEntity()
    {
        TestIIdentifiableEntity() testClass = new TestIIdentifiableEntity();
        testClass.Test();        
    }
}
```

These two test classes are already up and running, however, I would like to find a way to mix them together so that I can call the test methods from the same test class, after checking the type of the generic type. My idea is to get something like:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class TestBase<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestClass()
    {
        if (typeof(T) is IIdentifiableEntity<long>)
        {
            TestIIdentifiableEntity() testClass = new TestIIdentifiableEntity();
            testClass.Test();  
        }
        else
        {
            TestIEntity() testClass = new TestIEntity();
            testClass.Test();   
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the above solution but the program doesn't execute what is inside the `if` statement.

My question is: is what I'm trying to do possible? If so how do I check that a generic type implements `IIdentifiableEntity<long>`?

I tried browsing some questions but none of them apply to my case.

Thank you in advance, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: On a broader scope, any time I see a generic class/method declaration followed by `if (typeof(T)) ...`,  whistles start blowing... If you are doing that, the method/type is *not* generic by definition. Something is simply not right in your approach;  your code should work for *any* type; that is the whole purpose of generics.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @InBetween. I just thought that, since I have an inheritance chain on the interfaces, I could simplify things and not have two separate classes for each interface. That way when I extend the 'TestEntity' class I don't need to worry about what class to inherit from, the class deals with it and behaves accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Type.IsAssignableTo(Type)`

```
typeof( T ).IsAssignableTo( typeof( IIdentifiableEntity<long> ) )
```

Comment: This seems to work. I tried this before but I couldn't get it to work. I will test this further and accept your answer.  Thank you